# Python libtorrent creates empty torrent with magnet link

Tags: python, bittorrent, libtorrent, magnet-uri, libtorrent-rasterbar

I tried to download a torrent (the specific .torrent file) given *only* an info_hash. I know this was discussed here before, I even searched and modified my code accordingly. The result is the following:

```
import libtorrent as lt
import time
import sys
import bencode

ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
params = {
    'save_path': '.',
    'storage_mode': lt.storage_mode_t(2),
    'paused': False,
    'auto_managed': True,
    'duplicate_is_error': True
    }

info_hash = "2B3AF3B4977EB5485D39F96FE414729530F48386"
link = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:" + info_hash

h = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, link, params)

ses.add_dht_router("router.utorrent.com", 6881)
ses.add_dht_router("router.bittorrent.com", 6881)
ses.add_dht_router("dht.transmissionbt.com", 6881)
ses.start_dht()

while (not h.has_metadata()):
    time.sleep(1)

torinfo = h.get_torrent_info()

fs = lt.file_storage()
for f in torinfo.files():
  fs.add_file(f)
torfile = lt.create_torrent(fs)
torfile.set_comment(torinfo.comment())
torfile.set_creator(torinfo.creator())

f = open("torrentfile.torrent", "wb")
f.write(lt.bencode(torfile.generate()))
f.close()
```

This produces a torrent file, that cannot be loaded by transmission. It lacks trackers as well as the real pieces (creates \x00 instead of the actual pieces).
The following line *would* save the pieces, but still lacks the trackers and is not able to be opened by transmission:

```
f = open("torrentfile.torrent", "wb")
f.write(lt.bencode(torinfo.metadata()))
f.close()
```

How can I create a torrent, that looks like the actual torrent, by just using the magnet link (as stated in the code)?
(I am using Ubuntu 15.04 x64 with libtorrent 0.16.18-1)

I am not illegally downloading the file behind the torrent- however, I have the torrent to be compared to the torrent downloaded by my script.

Comment: can you please help me out? I'm using the same code as your's but in my case it stuck in the loop `while (not h.has_metadata()):`. any though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting piece hashes and the piece size (of the `file_storage` object). See the [documentation](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Create_Torrents.html#create_torrent).

However, a simpler and more robust way of creating a .torrent file is to use the `create_torrent` constructor that directly takes a `torrent_info` object. i.e.:

```
torfile = lt.create_torrent(h.get_torrent_info())
f = open("torrentfile.torrent", "wb")
f.write(lt.bencode(torfile.generate()))
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This really solves the problem of setting the pieces without the metadata() call. However, is there a way to get the trackers? Or do I have to add arbitrary trackers and hope they have seeders for this torrent?

Comment: trackers are not part of the metadata that get transferred over the ut_metadata protocol. If you know what the trackers are, you can add them manually to the create_torrent object before calling generate(). Adding trackers will not alter the info-hash.

Comment: But is there a way to determine the trackers without having the original torrent? So, can I get the trackers somehow? Otherwise I won't be able to open the torrent in e.g. transmission (it couldn't get seeders from trackers).

Comment: The only way to get trackers from a magnet link is for the link itself to contain trackers (&tr=). are you sure transmission requires trackers? That sounds strange, transmission supports the DHT, no?. Worst case, you can always add a dummy tracker pointing to 127.0.0.1

Comment: "Require" is maybe misleading. If I add the torrent, produced by my script, transmission is waiting for seeders. At least 1 hour before I give up (if I add the torrent with the trackers, I almost instantly get seeders). I marked your answer as the right one, since it solved most of my problems and made my code prettier ;)

Comment: perhaps the DHT is disabled in transmission, or it fails to bootstrap